# class inheritance in python as fields - side effects / incorrect handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, composition

Take the following simplified class structure which is used to clean and structure data from a legacy system.

- ProductModels contain fields
- Fields are their own classes and types on which a bunch of cleaning is done.

Overall the approach works like a charm in our use-case. But there is an issue where newly set products hold values from a previously generated product is the field is unused.

The minimal reproducible structure for Field / ProductModel looks like:

```py
class BaseManager:
    database_settings = {}

    def __init__(self, model_class):
        self.model_class = model_class

    def build_query(self):
        pass

    def connection(self):
        pass

    def run_query(self):
        pass

    def select(self):
        pass

class MetaModel(type):
    manager_class = BaseManager

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        field_list = []
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(v, Field):
                v.field_name = k
                v.table_name = attrs.get('table_name')
                field_list.append(k)


        cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        cls.__field_list__ = field_list

        return cls

    def _get_manager(cls):
        return cls.manager_class(model_class=cls)

    @property
    def objects(cls):
        return cls._get_manager()


class Field:
    def __init__(self, field_name, value=None):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.value = value

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value


class ProductModel(metaclass=MetaModel):
    sku = Field('sku')
    name = Field('name')

    table_name = 'my_table'

    def __init__(self, **field_data):
        for field_name, value in field_data.items():
            getattr(self, field_name).set_value(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sku.value=}, {self.name.value=}"
```

Now look at the first example:

```py
   ...: prod = ProductModel(sku='124', name='Name')
   ...: print(prod)
self.sku.value='124', self.name.value='Name'
```

The value for the sku = 124, which is correct.
The value for the name = "Name", which is also correct.

But now, the second example:

```
   ...: prod_two = ProductModel(sku='789')
   ...: print(prod_two)
self.sku.value='789', self.name.value='Name'
```

The value for sku has changed to 789, correct.
BUT the value for name, has remained "Name" instead of being None

It seem that when I create a new product, the field values are somehow kept from the initial product instead of being re-initialised.

One way of handling it, would be to reset all the field values upon a new ProductModel.**init**().  But this feels like a poor solution.  Instead I would rather understand better how to initialise the classes correctly.

Can you show me the right way?

Comment: There is no inheritance happening here. If a class contains attributes of different class, that is called **composition**.

Comment: ty, I adjusted the tags

Answer (score 2):

```
class ProductModel:
    sku = Field('sku')
    name = Field('name')
```

This defines something known as **class attribute**. These are **supposed** to be shared between different instances of the class. In fact, would you check back on your `prod` after creating `prod_two`, you will see that it had changed value to `789`. That shows us that both `prod.sku` and `prod_two.sku` are the same object.

In order to define **instance attributes**, you need to assign them on instance, for example in the `__init__`.

```
class ProductModel:
    def __init__(self, **field_data):
        self.sku = Field('sku')
        self.name = Field('name')
        for field_name, value in field_data.items():
            getattr(self, field_name).set_value(value)
```

Comment: I see, it's by design.   That suggestion doesn't work in this use-case, the complete version of the code relies on the fact that these fields are declared as attributes before __init__. Is there a way to ensure the classes are not shared?

Comment: @S.D. no, those are class variables. The *whole point* is that they are shared. if you don't want that, then use *instance variables*. What, exactly, relies on these class variables?\

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga There is a meta-class that's adjusting the attribute classes based on another attribute of the ProductModel class.  This is later used, to determine sql-queries against a microsoft sql server.  The meta-class is also exposing some methods that call the manager that does the sql-query generation.

Comment: @S.D. well, then you are probably going to need to introspect the fields, check if there is no corresponding instance attribute, and set it to `None`

Comment: @S.D. In that case it'd probably be worth to include MRE of such metaclass as they may change class behaviour drastically.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, perhaps so. I'll further my efforts to either set None - or perhaps re-initialise the fields with the right info before populating them.

Comment: @matszwecja example updated.

Comment: @S.D. Your example code doesn't use that metaclass in any way.

Comment: @matszwecja seems I forgot the include the declaration in the ProductModel. The original code is structured differently.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Following your suggestion, I ended up doing a deepcopy() for every field and setting None on that field.  This ensured that neither historic nor future field values are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions of @matszwecja and @juanpa.arrivillaga, I created copies of the fields in the ProductModel.**init**() and set those to None.

```
class ProductModel(metaclass=MetaModel):
    sku = Field('sku')
    name = Field('name')

    table_name = 'my_table'

    def __init__(self, **field_data):
        for field_name in self.__field_list__:
            field = getattr(self, field_name)
            field_copy = deepcopy(field)
            field_copy.value = None
            setattr(self, field_name, field_copy)

        for field_name, value in field_data.items():
            getattr(self, field_name).set_value(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sku.value=}, {self.name.value=}"
```

These ensured that the examples are now showing the expected behaviour:

```
   ...: prod = ProductModel(sku='124', name='Name')
   ...: print(prod)
self.sku.value='124', self.name.value='Name'
   ...: prod_two = ProductModel(sku='789')
   ...: print(prod_two)
self.sku.value='789', self.name.value=None
```

If I wouldn't copy the fields, and just set them None, it would correct the current ProductModel instance, but would also affect the historic ones.  By using deepcopy() we ensure every instance has their own, unshared fields.